# plsql trigger to auto insert id's

Tags: plsql, triggers, insert

So I am a noob at PL-SQL and am trying to learn it at the moment. When reading about triggers I was struck with the question of if I could use a trigger BEFORE insert to fill in a column for the insert.

EX. Take the classic employee table example. Say someone calls INSERT and passes values of all of the columns.  This means that they give a value for the employees id. Is it possible to have a trigger that will disregard what the user puts as the employees id and instead insert the next incremental id?
IE. If a someone passes in an ID of 202 but the last ID given was 173, the trigger would change the given id to be 174.

I come from a semi-strong programming background but I'm not sure how I would change the value for the user's given employee id because we aren't explicitly passed it as a parameter.

Sorry if it is a begginers question but I havent found an answer with google.

Comment: This may already be a covered topic on SO, but it may not be easy to find without knowing the terminology.  I've posted my own approach used over the years as an Oracle database developer...

Answer (score 3):

## Maintaining a Unique Key With a Auto Incremented PL/SQL Trigger

> I have used the popular Oracle default table known as "emp".  It has had previous incarnations in older database releases as a demo table from the [HR schema: SCOTT`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SCOTT).

You can accomplish this task with a simple PL/SQL Trigger accompanied by a Oracle Sequence object. An example that I cut and paste for myself in my own table designs looks like:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE   "EMP_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 
   INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 8000 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "EMP_TRG1" 
          before insert on emp
          for each row
          begin
              if :new.empno is null then
                  select emp_seq.nextval into :new.empno from dual;
             end if;
          end;
/
ALTER TRIGGER  "EMP_TRG1" ENABLE
/
```

For the newcomer to PL/SQL... the first schema object referenced in the code above is a Oracle PL/SQL `SEQUENCE` object.

### Oracle PL/SQL SEQUENCE Objects

Developers often rely on these to keep their sanity as it is the gatekeeper of uniqueness.  No matter where the request comes from or how many simultaneous calls to this object are made, it will issue a sequenced value exactly once.  Try it once you've created it:

```
SELECT emp_seq.nextval FROM DUAL;
```

There are some style choices here as Oracle 11gR2 and higher has released some of the original restrictions in coding syntax...

Assigning a new sequence value by using `SELECT INTO...` is not necessary.  Oracle 11g allows direct assignment of a sequence value, such as:

```
v_somevar:= emp_seq.nextval;
```

Coupling this with a trigger action is optional, but it gets you the complete task of auto assigning a field value.

### Using an Oracle PL/SQL Trigger to Assign Uniquely Sequenced ID's

An `INSERT` command that runs *without the trigger* would look like:

```
INSERT INTO emp(empno, ename, job, mgr...)
SELECT emp_seq.nextval, 'XAVIER', 'ANALYST', ...
  FROM dual;

COMMIT;
```

If you relied on the trigger, you could skip the `empno` value altogether to get an automatically assigned sequence id.

```
INSERT INTO emp(ename, job, mgr,...)
VALUES ('XAVIER', 'ANALYST', ... );

COMMIT;
```

**alternatively...**

```
INSERT INTO emp(empno, ename, job, mgr, ...)
VALUES (null, 'XAVIER', 'ANALYST', ...);

COMMIT;
```

Not mentioning a column value in an insert command is the same as assigning a NULL value to it.  This is the meaning of the IF-THEN-ELSE block contained within the trigger.

**The Original Request:**

To accomplish the functionality of the OP, you would need to rearrange the conditional block to consider a real input value assigned to the primary key, `EMPNO` by the `INSERT` statement issued against the table.

### Some Built-in Conventions in PL/SQL Trigger Coding (Before Insert Trigger):

Using code that acts before the insert command is executed is the right choice.  This would mean a [BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_insert.php) is what you need to manage an auto increment sequence assignment.

The values you need to pay close attention to within the trigger code are the ones assigned to the **BEFORE** and **AFTER** trigger states labeled as `NEW` and `OLD`.  The prefixed "colon" (":") is necessary to the syntax.

Each column in the table referenced by the trigger can be prefixed by `:NEW` and `:OLD` notation, as in:  `:NEW.empno` or `:NEW.ename`.

In the case of a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, there are no `:OLD` values. (See the linked reference, or do a search on your own). They (`:OLD` values) should not be referenced or assigned.  `:NEW` represents values that were assigned in the `INSERT` statement and can further be changed within the trigger before the insert is executed.